# Apache2 mod_rewrite to custom maintenance.html page

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2, maintenance-mode

I have the following situation. I have for my webapp under /var/www the folder "my_project". Now I want to display a maintenance page using mod_rewrite.

For this I have placed under /var/www the file "maintenance.html". Additionally I added the following rewrite conditions including the following rewrite rule in the config file for the "my_project" folder under /etc/apache2/sites-available :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName my_project.de
    ServerAlias www.my_project.de

    DocumentRoot /var/www/my_project.de/public

    <Directory /var/www/my_project.de/public/>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
    </Directory>

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond /var/www/maintenance.html -f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/maintenance\.html$
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^00\.00\.00\.000
    RewriteRule ^ - [R=503]
    ErrorDocument 503 /var/www/maintenance.html
    

    LogLevel debug
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Now I get the message "Service Unavailble. The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later", if the file "maintenance.html" is located in the folder /var/www. However, I want the maintenance.html file to be displayed instead of the message described above.

Can anyone tell me what I may be doing wrong or understanding here?

**UPDATE:**

I adjusted the config file and the above config represents the current situation. However this seems to result in a redirect loop. Because in the error.log file of apache is the following written:

Error logs:

```
AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /var/www/maintenance.html
AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /var/www/maintenance.html
AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /var/www/maintenance.html
AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /var/www/maintenance.html
AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /var/www/maintenance.html
AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /var/www/maintenance.html
AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /var/www/maintenance.html
AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /var/www/maintenance.html
AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /var/www/maintenance.html
AH00122: redirected from r->uri = /login
```

Note: I already tried a relative path vor the maintenance.html file but that did not work as well (e.g. /maintenance.html)

**FINAL SOLUTION:**

Thanks to @MrWhite I got it working.
The final vHost config looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName my_project.de
    ServerAlias www.my_project.de
    
    Alias /errordocs /var/www

    # Permit access to the Alias target
    <Directory /var/www>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorDocument 503 /errordocs/maintenance.html

    DocumentRoot /var/www/my_project.de/public

    <Directory /var/www/my_project.de/public/>
      Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
      AllowOverride All
      Require all granted
    </Directory>

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond /var/www/maintenance.html -f
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^00\.00\.00\.000
    RewriteRule ^ - [R=503]

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

In order to "activate" the maintenance mode it is now only required to place a "maintenance.html" file in the directory "var/www/".

Comment: "the following rewrite rule in the config file for the "my_project" folder" - how are you targeting the `my_project` subdirectory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule (.*) /maintenance.html [R=503,L]
> ```

When using the `R` flag with a non-3xx status, the *substitution* string is ignored (you should ideally include a single hyphen as the substitution in this case).

To serve `/maintenance.html` in this case you should set an appropriate `ErrorDocument` and simply use the `R=503` flag in the `RewriteRule` directive to trigger this via an internal subrequest.

For example

```
ErrorDocument 503 /maintenance.html

:
RewriteRule ^ - [R=503]
```

The `L` flag is  also unnecessary when specifying a non-3xx status, since it is implied.

If the rule is inside a `<Directory>` block that targets the `my_project` subdirectory then you don't need the *condition* that checks the request is not already `/maintenance.html`. The `ErrorDocument` should probably be defined outside of the `<Directory>` container.

---

**UPDATE:**

The `ErrorDocument` directive requires a root-relative URL-path, not an absolute file-path. Consequently this error document needs to exist within the confines of the vHost. It would seem from your updated config that the `my_project` "subdirectory" is in fact its own vHost, not a subdirectory off the "parent" (as I assumed).

If you want to use an `ErrorDocument` that is located elsewhere on the filesystem (ie. outside of the vHost) then you could use an [`Alias`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#alias) to point to this other location.

For example, in your existing vHost for `my_project.de`:

```
Alias /errordocs /var/www

# Permit access to the Alias target
<Directory /var/www>
    Require all granted
</Directory>

ErrorDocument 503 /errordocs/maintenance.html
```

Alternatively you could configure `/var/www/my_project.de/public/maintenance.html` as a *symlink* to `/var/www/maintenance.html`.

> ```
>  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/maintenance\.html$
> ```

This *condition* will need to be modified to include the `/errordocs` prefix. Alternatively, remove this *condition* altogether and modify the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. For example:

```
RewriteRule !^/errordocs/maintenance\.html$ - [R=503]
```

A minor issue with your existing mod_rewrite implementation is that direct requests to the `ErrorDocument` itself will be served with a 200 OK status and potentially be indexed by search engines. (Not that this should be a serious issue since the location of this file is unknown to the user - better than when it is located in the document root). However, this can be resolved with the following instead:

```
# Trigger a 503 for all "user" requests
RewriteCond /var/www/maintenance.html -f
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^203\.0\.113\.111
RewriteRule ^ - [R=503]
```

The check against the `REDIRECT_STATUS` environment variable ensures that only direct requests from the client are processed, not internal subrequests.

Comment: Thanks for the response MrWhite. I tried to adjust this as you said. However my adjustments result in an redirect loop. I have adjusted my post accordingly with the new info. Do you have any idea what the problem is?

Comment: @schwaluck The `ErrorDocument` requires a root-relative URL-path, not an absolute file-path. However, the "problem" would seem to be that you are trying to access a file that is essentially "outside" of the VirtualHost. I've updated my answer.