# Rewrite Rule not working within <If>-block in .htaccess on Apache 2.4

Tags: if-statement, mod-rewrite, apache2.4

I'm lost. My Rewrite Rule does work fine till the moment that I place it within an `<If>`-block.

When I search here for answers, via google, and via ChatGPT, I do get a mixed image of whether this is possible at all, or not.

Anyone a suggestion what I might have to change to get this working on the Apache 2.4 server of my webhoster?

```
SetEnv MAINTENANCE_MODE 1

RewriteEngine On

# REWRITE REQUESTS TO /MAINTENANCE(/) TO /MAINTENANCE.HTML
RewriteRule ^maintenance/?$ /maintenance.html [L,END]

<If "%{ENV:MAINTENANCE_MODE} == '1'">
    
    # EXCLUDE IPS FROM THIS REWRITE
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=1.2.3.41
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=1.2.3.42

    # EXCLUDE MAINTENANCE.HTML AND THE MAINTENANCE URL ITSELF FROM BEING REDIRECTED
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/maintenance\.html$
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/maintenance/?$
    
    # REDIRECT ALL OTHER IPS TO THE MAINTENANCE PAGE
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /maintenance/ [R=302,L]

</If>
```

Btw - I've checked with `AddType application/x-lsphp83 .php` inside the `<If>`-block that the If-condition is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most probably due to the order of processing. `SetEnv` is processed very late. `<If>` expressions are evaluated early, but merged late. mod_rewrite is processed very early and behaves "differently" when enclosed in an `<If>` block.

Try the following instead...

- Use `SetEnvIf` to set the env var, which is processed early.
- No need for the `<If>` expression since the env var can be evaluated in a mod_rewrite *condition*.

For example:

```
SetEnvIf ^ ^ MAINTENANCE_MODE=1

RewriteEngine On

# REWRITE REQUESTS TO /MAINTENANCE(/) TO /MAINTENANCE.HTML
RewriteRule ^maintenance/?$ /maintenance.html [END]

# Only when MAINTENANCE_MODE is set
RewriteCond %{ENV:MAINTENANCE_MODE} =1

# EXCLUDE IPS FROM THIS REWRITE
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=1.2.3.41
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=1.2.3.42

# EXCLUDE MAINTENANCE.HTML AND THE MAINTENANCE URL ITSELF FROM BEING REDIRECTED
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/maintenance(\.html|/)?$

# REDIRECT ALL OTHER IPS TO THE MAINTENANCE PAGE
RewriteRule ^ /maintenance/ [R=302,L]
```

Although, consider sending a 503 instead to serve a custom maintenance page.

- [Apache2 mod_rewrite to custom maintenance.html page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75151346/apache2-mod-rewrite-to-custom-maintenance-html-page)

Comment: Aha. Kind of annoying that .htaccess coding isn't that straightforward in terms of logic at times. Your solution is actually an elegant one - thanks! And yes, the 503 code is indeed the better one to us, just copied that line from another part of my .htaccess file.